# String method and lists

Tags: python

I have a list of several lists letters. Each letter correspond to a number.

```
h = 1
w = 2
wh = 3

list = [["w, w, h, w, w, w, h"], ["w, h, w, w, h, wh, h"]]
```

I need to the list of letters to print:

```
print(list[0])
>> w, w, h, w, w, w, h
```

Then I need to strip the quotes away so I can get

```
print(stripped_list)
>>2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1
```

I'm getting an error when I try the string method (strip, replace, etc). Is there another method or a better way of displaying my info to get both the original letters as well as a list of the corresponding numbers. Thank you.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow. Questions seeking debugging help must provide a [mcve]. Please check out [help] for more information on crafting on-topic questions. "I am getting an error" is not an adequate problem specification. What have you tried, and what error are you getting exactly?

Comment: maybe you're applying `replace` on the list instead of list items?

Comment: No, you can't just "strip away the quotes" because they're part of the representation of any string. What you can do: `", ".join(str(globals()[name.strip()]) for name in "w, h, wh".split(","))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this, use a dictionary for your conversions, and unpack your results

```
d = {'h': 1, 'w': 2, 'wh': 3}
lst = [["w, w, h, w, w, w, h"], ["w, h, w, w, h, wh, h"]]

print(*lst[0])
print(*[d[i] for i in lst[0][0].split(', ')])
# w, w, h, w, w, w, h
# 2 2 1 2 2 2 1
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @Feick :) glad to help love me some piano